# Is it possible to combine Sitecore 9.1+DotNet+React Js

Tags: mvc, react

I have a requirement in my project. It is an existing project which is developed in Dotnet MVC + Sitecore 9.1, so some part of the page in that project needs to be implemented in react js, for example, calling the service and filtering the data. My question is how we can integrate the react js with this existing project that has MVC + Sitecore 9.1 ? Is there any way to do all this things? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96063/discussion-on-question-by-durga-prasad-is-it-possible-to-combine-sitecore-9-1do).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Yes - Sitecore JSS / Headless Services

The officially supported [Sitecore Headless Services](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/190/sitecore-headless-development) has full support for ReactJS components on MVC pages in the form of Javascript Renderings or Client Side Embedding.

#### Sitecore JavaScript renderings

[Sitecore JavaScript renderings](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/190/sitecore-headless-development/sitecore-jss-integration-in-mvc-solutions.html) offer support for both server-side and client-side rendering of ReactJS components on an existing Sitecore MVC page.

#### Client Side Embedding

[Client Side Embedding](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/190/sitecore-headless-development/sitecore-jss-integration-in-mvc-solutions.html) is a simple approach for client-side only rendering of ReactJS components, especially if not aiming to have ReactJS drive the page layout.

### Other Options

There is also a community supported extension of [ReactJS.NET](https://reactjs.net/) which is [Sitecore.React](https://github.com/GuitarRich/sitecore.react). However the following considerations should be taken into account when deciding which direction to go:

- JSS is officially supported and maintained for Sitecore 9.1+
- ReactJS.NET and Sitecore.React are not officially supported by Sitecore
- JSS supports the Experience Editor, Sitecore.React also supports the Experience Editor, but does require you to call `FieldRenderer.Render(item, "field")` in the controller.
- JSS supports the Tracker (for Analytics, Personalisation and Optimization),
- Sitecore.React also supports the Tracker with no extra code.
- JSS is more scalable as it has headless support, whereas the community modules above are coupled to .NET MVC.
- JSS has support for Sitecore Experience Accelerator in Sitecore 9.2+
- JSS requires your Sitecore license has this enabled - you will need to check your license details or contact your account manager to confirm.
- Sitecore.React does not require any extra licenses
- Sitecore.React has better support for hybrid modes. JSS can do a JavaScript rendering, but these do not scale well due to the SSR call made to the node server per rendering.
- Sitecore.React does not have a dependency on node.js.

Comment: Just to clarify, with Sitecore.React, you don't need to write any extra code or effort for the Experience Editor, it supports this out of the box. Same with Tracker for analytics. Because it is just a controller rendering, it works just the same. You can personalize, a/b test etc... everything that you can do with a controller rendering... :)

Comment: Also - please note that the JSS JavaScript Rendering part is still experimental and is only designed for 1-2 components per page. It does not scale well due to the SSR call to the node service.

Comment: Agreed with @Richard Seal about number of JSS component per page for performance

Comment: Note that JSS Javascript Renderings are deprecated and no longer support since they do not scale well, and it is generally recommended that they are avoided. https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/mvc-integration/javascript-rendering#sitecore-javascript-rendering-deprecated